# sort a string alphabetically but if a string is present completely as a prefix in another string, then string with longer length should come first

Tags: java, arrays, string

Question. Sort a string aplhabetically, but if a string is present completely as a prefix in another string, then string with longer length should come first. Eg bat, batman are 2 strings and the string bat is present as a prefix in Batman - then sorted order should have - Batman, bat.

here is the Code-
could anyone tell me what should I do for checking if a string is present completely as a prefix in another string,and sort accordingly.

Input-

```
3
bat
apple
batman
```

Output-

```
apple
batman
bat
```

**My code:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class sortStrings {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        String[] str = new String[n];
        for(int j=0;j<str.length;j++)
        {
             str[j] = sc.next();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<str.length-1;++i)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<str.length;++j)
            {
                if(str[i].compareTo(str[j])>0)
                {
                String temp = str[i];
                str[i]=str[j];
                str[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(str[i]);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You could use a `Comparator` for this `Comparator<String> cmp = (a, b) -> a.startsWith(b) ? 1 : b.startsWith(a) ? -1 : a.compareToIgnoreCase(b);` and then let the JDK do the sort for you: `Arrays.sort(str, cmp);` If you can't use a comparator you can have a look at `String.startsWith()` which is exactly what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match the swapped strings again to meet the criteria, `but if a string is present completely as a prefix in another string, then string with longer length should come first`. Do it using [String::regionMatches(int offset, String other, int ooffset, int len)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches(int,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) as shown below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        String[] strArr = new String[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < strArr.length; j++) {
            strArr[j] = sc.next();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length - 1; ++i) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < strArr.length; ++j) {
                if (strArr[i].compareTo(strArr[j]) > 0) {
                    swap(strArr, i, j);
                }
                if (strArr[j].regionMatches(0, strArr[i], 0, strArr[i].length())) {
                    swap(strArr, i, j);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(strArr[i]);
        }
    }

    static void swap(String[] strArr, int i, int j) {
        String temp = strArr[i];
        strArr[i] = strArr[j];
        strArr[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
3 bat apple batman
apple
batman
bat
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            if(o1.toLowerCase().startsWith(o2.toLowerCase())) {
                return -1;
            }
            if(o2.toLowerCase().startsWith(o1.toLowerCase())) {
                return 1;
            }

            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    };

    String[] str = {"apple", "batman", "bat", "mangoman","mango","super","superman"};
    Arrays.sort(str, comparator);
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str));
}
```

output

```
[apple, batman, bat, mangoman, mango, superman, super]
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Try with the input already correctly sorted: `"apple", "batman", "bat"`, will yield `"apple", "bat", "batman"`. You'd also need to check the startsWith the other way around

Comment: @lino Tank you , rectified the code. Please have a look

Comment: This will probably work, though I am a bit puzzled why you use `o1.toLowerCase().startsWith(o2.toLowerCase())` and then `o2.indexOf(o1)==0`, why not use startsWith again? also why not ignore the case in the second `if` and the last statement?

Comment: @Lino yupp I was in a hury made the changes again